# delete all cells of a certain color

Tags: vba, excel, fonts, colors

This seems relatively simple and as I understand, it is possible. But I can't seem to figure it out or find exactly what I am looking for on the internet.

I have some excel data in column A and some of the data is blue (0,0,255), some is red (255,255,255), some is green (0, 140, 0). I want to delete all blue data.

I was told that:

```
Sub test2()
    Range("A2").DisplayFormat.Font.Color
End Sub
```

Would give me the colors... but when I run that it says invalid use of the property and highlights .color

Instead I clicked on the:
    Font color drop down
        then more colors
            then custom colors
                then I can see that the data in blue is at (0,0,255)

So then I tried:

```
Sub test()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wbk.Sheets(1)

Dim cell As Range

With ws
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A:A").Cells
        'cell.Value = "'" & cell.Value
        For i = 1 To Len(cell)
            If cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) Then
                If Len(cell) > 0 Then
                    cell.Characters(i, 1).Delete
                End If
                If Len(cell) > 0 Then
                    i = i - 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next cell
End With

End Sub
```

I found this on the web as a solution in several places but when I run it, nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Do you mean some of the data within a given cell is different colours? Also, if applied to cell, is it conditional formatting or regular fill?

Comment: It is not conditional formatting, it was copied and pasted from a word document. And a single cell only contains one color. For example A1 = blue font, A2 = red font, A3 = Green font, then the next 4 cells might be blue... then the next 2 might be green... etc...

Comment: I recreated this manually and your macro worked for me, it got rid of any cells that are with the color 0,0,255, are you sure the sheet is correct?

Comment: I think you misunderstood... the background color of the cell is white (no color) but the text is blue (the font color).

Comment: is the font color the same for all characters of a cell?

Comment: @XCELLGUY, is the font color the same for all characters of a cell?

Comment: yes the is the same color for all characters of a cell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basic, if your cells with blue font are not deleted then the font is a different color. Change the range to meet your needs.

```
For Each cel In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A30")
    If cel.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) Then cel.Delete
Next cel
```

Updated to allow user to select the first cell in the column with the font color, obtain the font color, and clear all the cells that match the font color.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a Cell:", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim lr As Long
        lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim x As Long
        x = rng.Row

        For i = lr To x Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 1).Font.Color = rng.Font.Color Then .Cells(i, 1).Clear
        Next i
    End With
```

Comment: Ok this works... I had to add "dim cel as range" at the beginning and change ".delete" to ".clearcontents" because otherwise everything shifted up... and i didn't want that... and i changed the range to A:A because i don't know how many rows i will have and it will vary... It works... but its slow... probably for the reasons QHarr pointed out below but i couldn't get his to work.

Comment: Copy, just giving the basic code, `Delete` was used because it was in your question. I'm glad you could modify it to meet your needs.

Comment: see bottom... i will post final code... was able use a snippet from a previous life that finds the last row which is significantly faster than range A:A

Answer (score 1):

Something like following where all qualifying cells are gathered together, using `Union`, and deleted in one go. If deleting entire rows individually, you always need to loop backwards. Deleting/clearing in one go is more efficient.

```
Sub test()
    Dim wbk As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, currentCell As Range, unionRng As Range

    Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        For Each currentCell In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)  '<==assuming actual data present
            If  currentCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) Then
                If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set unionRng = Union(currentCell, unionRng)
                Else
                    Set unionRng = currentCell
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.Delete
End Sub
```

---

[image]

Comment: It's been awhile, but I'm actually looking for a way to delete tens of thousands of rows at once and IIRC large unions can be problematic and slow - just something to consider.

Answer (score 1):

you coudl use `Range` object `Autofilter()` method with `xlFilterFontColor` operator;

```
Sub test()       
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(0, 0, 255), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 0 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        If .Range("A1").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) Then .Range("A1").ClearContents ' check first row, too (which is excluded by AutoFilter)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't want to delete the row... only the text within the cell

Comment: @XCELLGUY, it'd be nice of you to give proper feedback to people trying helping you

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Sub test2()

Dim cel As Range
Dim LR As Long

LR = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

For Each cel In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & LR)

    If cel.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) Then cel.ClearContents
Next cel
End Sub
```