# how to delete files in a folder that are in column B and red

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, delete-file

I need assistance. I need to delete old files in a folder. I have a list of the files in column B and the old files are colored RGB(255,0,0). Assuming that the code would read something like:

```
   Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim cell As Variant
Dim source As Range
Set source = Range("c3:c8")
MyFolder = Sheets("Delete Revs").Range("K1").Value & "\"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\" & "*.*")
    For Each cell In source
        If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
        Kill MyFile
        Else
        End If
Next
```

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: `If Cell.Interior.Color = vbRed Then: Kill Cell.Value` etc.

Comment: I am not sure how to write the code. I am still new and i can not find examples of what i want to do.

Comment: i just tried this code. "Edited the original"

Comment: i get a run time error '53'  file not found.  file name is AG-130202-P311-02   and is a .pdf file.

Comment: [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332406/delete-all-cells-of-a-certain-color). There's plenty of free VBA tutorials out there to help you get started on writing code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
Sub DeleteFiles()
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim cell As Variant
Dim source As Range

MyFolder = Sheets("Delete Revs").Range("K1").Value & "\"
Set source = Range("c3:c8")

For Each cell In source
    If cell.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
        MyFile = MyFolder & cell.Value
        If Dir(MyFile) <> "" Then
            Kill MyFile
            cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen 'changing the color when file deleted
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DeleteFiles()

    Dim myFolder, myFile As String
    Dim Cel As Variant

    myFolder = Sheet1.[A1] & "\" 'Folder Path

  'Looping for Visible Cells Only
    For Each Cel In Sheet1.Range("C3:C8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        myFile = myFolder & Cel 'File Path

        If Cel.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
            If Len(Dir$(myFile)) > 0 Then    'If File Exits in Folder
                Kill (myFile)  'Delete File
            End If
        End If

    Next Cel
End Sub
```